# Using iron-ajax of Google Polymer, how to load a json file from any web server

Tags: polymer

I am developing a Google Polymer web application. It needs to load JSON files from a web server. I am using iron-ajax, as recommended in the Polymer documentation.

I copied the sample code from the demo into my project and tested it many times, but all tests failed. Please show me what is wrong in my code.

template

```
    ......

    <iron-ajax
    on-response="ontap"
    auto
    url="test.json" 
    // for one test, I put test.json in the same folder as this Polymer html
    // for other tests, I put test.json on some web servers, using correct URLs
    //for example: http://www.test.com/test.json
    handle-as="json"
    last-response="{{ajaxR}}"
    debounce-duration="300"> </iron-ajax>  
    .......
```

Polymer function

```
    ontap:function(ev){ 
    alert(ev.detail);//it says "object HTMLElement"
    alert(this.ajaxR);//it says null 
    }
    .......
```

test.json

```
    [{song:"song1"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ajaxR` becomes a property on your element. To access it you can use `this.ajaxR`.

```
ontap: function () {
  alert(this.ajaxR);
  alert(this.ajaxR[0].song); 
}
```

Comment: I am very sorry. It 's my error spelling. I will correct it soon.

Comment: I got the event object for on-response of the iron-jax. Please could you give me how to get fields of ev.detail where ev is the event variable. And ev.detail says it is an object and HTMLElement.

Comment: The `ev` is the event that is fired when you click on the button which will be a HTML element. `this.ajaxR` will be the response of the Ajax call. Check you have the URL to the JSON correct.